# Making RPC calls without setting up my own node

Tags: web3js, nethereum, rpc

My application is using web3 or Nethereum to connect to my own ethereum node (setup using geth).

Is it a must for me to setup my own node to make RPC calls (or connect to a specific node that setup by someone else)? If this is the case, when my node is down, my application is down as well. It is not as *distributed* as it should be.

Comment: Ismael, thanks for the info. My question is actually trying to achieve *distributed* instead of relying on one node. Anyway, I guess it cannot be done at the moment.

Comment: Infura is kinda of distributed, there are several nodes behind and it is switching internally so you are not aware of the change. Some dapps like MyEtherWallet let you choose which node to use from a set of predefined nodes or to use your own node, but the switch is manual.